# Blender 2.80: Left Mouse Button is moving cursor, not selecting (despite proper keymap settings)

Tags: selection-tools, shortcut

I'm using v2.80.  I have chosen "Select with: Left Mouse Button", and as far as I can tell, the LMB is supposed to Select.  Instead, it's moving the cursor around.

It seems like moving the cursor is supposed to be <kbd>Shift</kbd> + RMB, which works.

In the keymap settings, it's configured correctly:

- Select: LMB
- Set 3D Cursor: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + RMB

Yet, the behavior I'm experiencing is that LMB is moving the cursor, rather than selecting.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + LMB is working, so I can just do that.  But this seems like a bug.  But this is also my second day with Blender, so there might be something I'm missing.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. I'd suggest backing up the keymap configuration and do a reset (File > Default > Load Factory Settings).

Comment: Awesome!! That worked, thanks.  Add as an answer?

Comment: I have the same problem just save and load it again it went back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case something goes wrong with the configuration, you can restore the default settings through *File > Default > Load Factory Settings*.

Answer (score 8):

Press <kbd>T</kbd>  to bring up the toolbar on the left.

You will find you have the *Cursor Tool* selected. Select the *Select Tool* at the top to restore default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug or something like that. I guess you accidentally pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and selected *Cursor*.

Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and select *Tweak* again as in the default settings. No need to reset Blender!

Comment: This is the correct answer. In all my years using Blender this has never been an issue until last night for me. And that fixed it instantly. No idea how that could have happened, but it clearly did.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT LOAD FACTORY SETTINGS! This is very dangerous. There are thousands of settings and if you have used Blender for any length of time you will probably change some obscure setting several levels deep that you had previously set the way you wanted and it might take hours to get it back to working condition. You will also lose add-ons, etc.

This is a bug in blender that pops up often. It is not a factory setting. If you have LMB set to select, sometimes Blender will just get in a mood to start using LMB to set the Cursor instead, and it is very hard to continue working. For a temp fix you can just quit and re-open blender.

After some trial and error I stumbled upon a trick that I think works. In the *Toolbar* on the left, *Menu-Click* on the *Cursor* Button (for me it is LMB). This will bring up a small *Tool Menu*. Select *Assign Shortcut*. It will bring up a prompt saying "Press a Key". Hit any key that you don't commonly use. This will re-assign the Cursor command away from your LMB. I'm not sure if this fixes the bug forever, I will have to keep workin and see if it pops up again.